# при клике на input скрывается клавиатура (Мобильная версия)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день при клике на поле поиска в шапке сразу прячется клавиатура на мобильной версии 768 px и меньше.
http://shop3.alicom.dp.ua

Подскажите в чем беда.

Comment: Причина в том что инпут теряет фокус при клике. Вероятнее всего, виноват в этом какой-то обработчик событий данного элемента (просмотрите код всех обработчиков).

Comment: В качестве временного костыля (пока ищете источник проблемы), можно использовать что-то типа `yourInput.addEventListener('click', e => setTimeout(() => e.target.focus(), 500));`