# На мобильной версии сайта на Андройд устройстве, при клике по input то на секунду появляется клавиатура, а затем исчезает

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, пробовал уже и вариант [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830585/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-input-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F), пробовал менять стили и писал такой скрипт и пробовал такие стили,  но ничего не помогает.

```js
 let timer;
                        const modalMapSearchInput = document.querySelector('#mb-map-search');

                        modalMapSearchInput.addEventListener('focus', () => {
                            clearTimeout(timer);

                            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                                if (modalMapSearchInput.value !== '') {
                                    modalMapSearchDropdown.classList.add('active');
                                    getPlacePredictions(modalMapSearchInput.value);
                                }
                            }, 300);
                        });

                        modalMapSearchInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
                            clearTimeout(timer);
                        });
```

```css
input {
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
```

вот сам код инпута с контейнером. Для справки это поисковая строка из OpenStreetMap и ссылка на мою [проблемную страницу](https://devmy.uz/ru/hotels/tashkent?hotel_id=&current-date-field=%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82&checkin=23.08.2023&checkout=24.08.2023&rooms=1&adults=2&children=0&local=1), на странице есть [image], это в десктоп версии и [image: введите сюда описание изображения] в мобильной

```html
<div class="mb-map__global-map" id="mb-map-container">
            <div class="mb-map__search">
                <div class="mb-map__search-field">
                    <svg class="mb-map__search-icon" width="18" height="17" viewBox="0 0 18 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M15.8338 16.1867L16.01 16.3436L16.1768 16.1768L16.6768 15.6768L16.8635 15.4901L16.6669 15.3138L12.1755 11.2882C13.0912 10.1752 13.6413 8.74939 13.6413 7.19563C13.6413 3.63581 10.7554 0.75 7.19563 0.75C3.63581 0.75 0.75 3.63581 0.75 7.19563C0.75 10.7554 3.63581 13.6413 7.19563 13.6413C8.75881 13.6413 10.1925 13.0845 11.3084 12.1588L15.8338 16.1867ZM1.9789 7.19563C1.9789 4.3145 4.3145 1.9789 7.19563 1.9789C10.0767 1.9789 12.4124 4.3145 12.4124 7.19563C12.4124 10.0767 10.0767 12.4124 7.19563 12.4124C4.3145 12.4124 1.9789 10.0767 1.9789 7.19563Z" fill="#949494" stroke="#949494" stroke-width="0.5"/>
                    </svg>
                    <button class="mb-map__search-reset active" id="mb-map-reset">
                        <svg width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 15 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M13.864 0.636056C13.6687 0.440794 13.3521 0.440794 13.1569 0.636056L7.5 6.29291L1.84315 0.636055C1.64788 0.440793 1.3313 0.440793 1.13604 0.636055C0.940778 0.831317 0.940778 1.1479 1.13604 1.34316L6.79289 7.00002L1.13604 12.6569C0.940777 12.8521 0.940777 13.1687 1.13604 13.364C1.3313 13.5592 1.64788 13.5592 1.84315 13.364L7.5 7.70712L13.1569 13.364C13.3521 13.5592 13.6687 13.5592 13.864 13.364C14.0592 13.1687 14.0592 12.8521 13.864 12.6569L8.20711 7.00002L13.864 1.34316C14.0592 1.1479 14.0592 0.831318 13.864 0.636056Z" fill="black"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="mb-map__search-input" id="mb-map-search" placeholder="{{ trans('frontend.map_search_placeholder') }}">
                                 </div>
                <div class="mb-map__dropdown mb-map__search-dropdown"></div>
            </div>
```